# Is it possible to have one Exception handler for multiple timers in a C# class?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, appdomain

I have a C# program which runs a system tray application - transferring / moving / creating / editing files in the background.

There is alot of exception handling and loop handling to prevent the program from crashing / getting stuck if the user manual deletes a file the program is working with.

Unfortunately one of the computer the program is running on is having the program crash. The computer is very hard to get, and cannot have debugging software loaded on (it is an embedded PC outside with no network access).

I have tried finding the cause of the crash (such as an unhandled exeption) however have not found anything and do not have access to the PC as it is in a remote location.

I was hoping to find a way to use AppDomain / an UnhandledExceptionEventHandler to catch all unhandled exceptions and log them for diagnosis.
However the exception I have (deliberately) created in the office inside the class "DoSomething.class", are crashing the WinForm application rather than logging the exception error.

My code is:

```
    //Current domain for the unhandled exception handling
    AppDomain currentDomain;

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlAppDomain)]
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UnhandledExceptionHandler);


        CreateTimer.Interval = Settings.Default.CreateTimer;
        CreateTimer.Start();
        RunCopyProtocol();

        ChangeFilesTimer.Interval = 10000;
        ChangeFilesTimer.Start();
        RunChangeFiles();

        throw new Exception("ABC");

    }

    public void UnhandledExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            Exception ex = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
            SetLabel(ex);
        }
        finally { }
    }

    private string SetLabel(Exception ex)
    {
        String str;

        str = ex.Message;
        Label1.Text = str;

        return str;
    }

    private void ChangeFilesTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunChangeFiles();
        throw new Exception("2");
    }
```

**Why doesn't the throw new exception call the unhandled exception error?
How would I use AppDomain to get the unhandled exception handler to handle this exception / exceptions in the RunChangeFiles?**

Code on AppDomain is based of [MSDN examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You may have a mistaken idea of what AppDomain.UnhandledException is going to allow you to do. It does not prevent the application from ending when an unhandled exception occurs. It is simply a notification that allows you to clean up or log before the process ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your timer is a `System.Timers.Timer` the reason is documented by MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx):

> The Timer component catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers for the Elapsed event.

Take a look at this similar question:
[How do I get the Exception that happens in Timer Elapsed event?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3749785/4267590)

You'll have to catch the exceptions that are thrown in the elapsed handler, and rethrow them on a ThreadPool thread.

Using your code above and extending the answer from the referenced question:

```
private void ChangeFilesTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        RunChangeFiles();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            _ => { throw new Exception("Exception on timer thread.", ex); });
    }
}
```

---

If your timer is a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` then you will need to hook into the [Application.ThreadException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to handle unhandled exceptions.

Subscribe to this event prior to calling `Application.Run()`.

---

You can also handle logging of the `Exception` in a local exception handling block before rethrowing the exception.

```
try
{
    /// ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is ArgumentException)
    {
        /// handle known or specific exceptions here
    }
    else 
    {
        /// log then rethrow unhandled exceptions here
        logExceptions(ex);
        throw;  
    }
}
```

Comment: If I put a "throw new Exception("TEST");"  Inside the MainForm(). It still throws the exception without being caught by the handler. Does the timer suppress other events simply by running? (i.e. not only when elapsed?)

Comment: public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UnhandledExceptionHandler);


        CreateTimer.Interval = Settings.Default.CreateTimer;
        CreateTimer.Start();
        RunCopyProtocol();

        ChangeFilesTimer.Interval = 10000;
        ChangeFilesTimer.Start();
        RunChangeFiles();
        throw new Exception("123")
    }
This was the code. With the new exception thrown at the end of MainForm() after the handler subscription

Comment: You are throwing the test exception on a UI thread.  To handle this you need to hook into the `Application.ThreadException` event.  Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5762806/4267590 and on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You are right creating "currentDomain" is unnecessary.

Comment: Previously I have only used AppDomain UnhandledExceptionEventHandler in a non-UI / non-timer thread. Evidently there was a lot more to it than I realised.

Comment: thank you. This will probably be the way I will have to do it. I was hopping to create a tool to catch any unhandled exceptions and narrow down what time (and so hopefully) where they were being thrown. This was to try and make best use of my time when I go out into the field where the PC is with my laptop.